# Compact Framework 2.0 FTP Server in C#

Tags: c#, ftp, compact-framework

I need to send and receive (some times large files) from a WIN CE 6 device. My initial thought was to write a C# Socket based client but then again it does the same as FTP. So just wondering whether I could find a Win CE Compact Framework based FTP Server/Client program and modify it to support my requirement or should I use TCP/IP ? Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need a client or a server?  For a client library, there's [one on Codeplex here](http://ftp.codeplex.com/).  For an FTP server, Windows CE already has one in the catalog - you can build it into the OS by including it in your OS design.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comment. I am interested in receiving files as well . So I need a FTP Server running on my device. i think OS design is not an option for me.

Comment: @Kakopappa You might be surprised, check to see if there is an FTP or SFTP running already on your device